# How can I create a bounded int in Python?

Tags: python, integer, limit, boundary, bounded-types

I want to create a class that subclasses from `int`, but sets a lower bound and upper bound on what number it can be be.

For example, if the lower bound is `2`, then `a = MyClass(1)` should raise an exception.

I'm struggling because `int` doesn't seem to have an `__init__` function, so I'm not sure how to subclass from it, and my attempts are giving me errors.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work both for `int`s and `float`s:

```py
def BoundedNumber(number_class):
    def BoundedNumberClassCreator(class_name, lower_bound, upper_bound):
        if upper_bound and lower_bound and upper_bound < lower_bound:
            raise ValueError(f"Upper bound {upper_bound} is lower than the lower bound {lower_bound}")

        def new(cls, number):
            if lower_bound and number < lower_bound:
                raise ValueError(f"{number} is below the lower bound of {lower_bound} for this class")

            if upper_bound and upper_bound < number:
                raise ValueError(f"{number} is above the upper bound of {upper_bound} for this class")

            return number_class(number)

        return type(class_name, (number_class,),
                    {"__new__": new,
                     "__doc__": f"Class that acts like `{number_class.__name__}` but has an inclusive lower bound of {lower_bound} and an inclusive upper bound of {upper_bound}",
                     "lower_bound": lower_bound,
                     "upper_bound": upper_bound})

    return BoundedNumberClassCreator

BoundedInt = BoundedNumber(int)
BoundedFloat = BoundedNumber(float)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    IntBetween50And150 = BoundedInt('IntBetween50And150', 50, 150)
    print(IntBetween50And150(100) == 100)  # True
    try:
        IntBetween50And150(200)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Caught the ValueError: {e}")  # Caught the value error: 200 is above the upper bound of 150 for this class

    print(IntBetween50And150(50.5))  # 50
    print(IntBetween50And150.__doc__) # Class that acts like `int` but has an inclusive lower bound of 50 and an inclusive upper bound of 150
```

The hard part with subclassing from `int` is that it doesn't have an `__init__` function. Instead, you have to use the `__new__` function.

The `BoundedNumber` class takes care of this, defining a `__new__` function that both runs the `int` (or `float`) `__new__` function by calling `int` (or `float`), but also runs its own checks on the bounds before doing so.

Since we want to dynamically create a new class, we're going to have to use the `type` function. This will allow us to create a new class with whatever bounds we want during runtime.

Technically, to answer your question, you only need the `BoundedNumberClassCreator` with `int` put in everywhere that the `number_class` is used, but since it works for `float`s as well, I figured I'd encapsulate it to reduce duplicate code.

One odd thing about this solution if if you `ZeroToOne = BoundedInt('ZeroToOne', 0, 1)` and then create `i = ZeroToOne(1.1)` it will throw an error, even though `int(1.1)` is within the designated range. If you don't like this functionality, you can swap the order of the checks and the return inside of the `new` method of the `BoundedNumberClassCreator`.

Answer (score 0):

This is right off the bat, not many errors are handled.

```
class boundedInt:

    def __init__(self, lower, upper):
        self.x = None
        if (lower <= upper):
            self.lower = lower
            self.upper = upper
        else:
            raise ValueError("Lower Bound must be lesser than Upper Bound".format())  

    def assign(self, x):
        if (x>= self.lower and x<=self.upper):
            self.x = x
            return self.x
        else:
            raise ValueError("Not in bounds")

myInt = boundedInt(15,20) # create object myInt
f = myInt.assign(17) # assigns value to a variable
```

Comment: I'd like it to subclass from `int`, if possible (for example, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677054/5049813))